# Issues synchronizing log files from Container to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, aws-cli, docker-container

I´m having some issues trying to synchronized in my container log file. Inside the container, there is a log file that should be sync into a bucket in S3; however, I´m constantly getting issues that the log file doesn´t exist:

[image: log error]

This is my basic **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim-buster
COPY log.txt log.txt
COPY ./target/AWS-Logger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar AWS-Logger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","AWS-Logger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

FROM amazon/aws-cli

RUN aws s3 sync data.txt s3://aws-test/logs/data.txt
```

The log file is generated by the jar while it´s running. Also, regarding the credentials, I´m sharing them via a Docker compose.

Any idea why the path is not visible? Or any better way to sync the file from the container to the S3 via Docker and Amazon CLI.

Comment: It looks like you're confused about the use of the `RUN` directive. `RUN` commands run when you are building the image, not when you are running a container. If your `data.txt` is generated by your Java code, then it won't exist until you actually start a container from the image.

Comment: Hi @larsks, okay, and how what would be your suggestion to access it or move it?